# How to get uid value of an android application from a list displayed in a spinner?

Tags: android

I am developing a small application which displays the installed application as a list in a spinner. Only the application name is displayed as spinner values. Whenever I select an application from spinner I need to retrieve the UID of the selected application. How can I implement the function?

The following is my code for getting the application name from the spinner

```
appspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int app_pos, long app_id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String app_selected=parent.getItemAtPosition(app_pos).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return;
        }
    });
```

The installed application is stored in a list using the PackageManager class and using PackageInfo class I am getting the name of the application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to use `PackageManager` to get the package information about whatever app you select in the list. I haven't done this with a `Spinner` but i'm sure it should work the same as it did in my `ListView`.

```
appspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int app_pos, long app_id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String app_selected=parent.getItemAtPosition(app_pos).toString();

        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        //get a list of installed apps.
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(
                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        int UID;
        //loop through the list of installed packages and see if the selected
        //app is in the list
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(app_selected)){
                //get the UID for the selected app
                UID = packageInfo.uid;
                break; //found a match, don't need to search anymore
            }

        }

        //Do whatever with the UID
        Log.i("Check UID", "UID is: " + UID);               

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return;
    }
});
```

You might want to see how `packageName` returns the `packageName` so you can try to match it with whatever was selected.

hope this points you in the right direction and helps you out. Good Luck.

Comment: Maybe add a `break;` after finding a match to avoid unnecessary processing :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @pablisco, I've made the edit.