# How to obtain amount of transferred data through Wi-Fi from other applications?

Tags: android-wifi, android

I'm facing to this problem. I spent much time by searching some `API` or *"something"* with it's possible to obtain transferred data through Wi-Fi from other applications (how screenshot bellow shows).

Does someone know a way how to do it? Is here someone who tried (or has already done) for something similar? Or a little differently: *Is this possible to do it?*

Currently i think that **this is not possible** because i think that non-system application cannot retrieve data from other application(s) installed on device. But maybe i can *"missing"* something so i placed this question and will be glad for whatever suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about WiFi, but for mobile data it must be because apps like Carphone Warehouse Bill Angel manage it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html)

```
Class that provides network traffic statistics. These statistics include bytes transmitted and received and network packets transmitted and received, over all interfaces, over the mobile interface, and on a per-UID basis.
```

This means you can use **getUidTxBytes** to get whole transmitted data and so far **getUidRxBytes** to get whole received data.

And you can get application's **UID** with:

```
getApplicationInfo().uid
```

or for other applications refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875916/how-to-get-uid-value-of-an-android-application-from-a-list-displayed-in-a-spinne)

Answer (score 3):

While Sercan's answer is correct, must warn you that TrafficStats is not always guaranteed to give you correct stats. Basically TrafficStats will check files in the directory /proc/uid_stat/1094/ and various files like tcp_snd, tcp_rcv etc under this directory. On some devices, these (pseudo)files are not updated. Hence you should always check for a return value of UNSUPPORTED (-1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#UNSUPPORTED

Also, typically these stats have not been including UDP data. So the numbers you report will be wrong for apps that use UDP (like VoIP apps). For more details, look at 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32410

On latest Android versions, there is another /proc file that gives you a lot of details. This is at /proc/self/net/xt_qtaguid/stats. But this pseudo file will only show the stats of an app reading that. Any Android app tries to read this file, it will not get stats related to any other Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try reading config files containing network information?
try this:
adb shell
cd /proc/uid_stat/XXXX(Proc id)
cat tcp_rcv/tcp_snd