# collects data transferred(upload/download) by mobile internet on android device

Tags: android, android-networking

How to  collects data **transferred(upload/download)** by `mobile internet` on android device from particular moment (date & time) and display it above status bar across the screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
 private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
        TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
        long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774/

Comment: I want to get data transfer from particular moment not from device booting the above methods you are using give data transfering amount from booting...

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to get transferred data on android from here [How to obtain amount of transferred data through Wi-Fi from other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453099/how-to-obtain-amount-of-transferred-data-through-wi-fi-from-other-applications/18696494#18696494)

and here's the notifications link,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

just a little google search.