# Android PACKAGE_ADDED for specific packages

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have added one broadcast receiver in my androidmanifest for "PACKAGE_ADDED" action.

This broadcast is received for all packages installation.

But I want to get intimated only for selected packages. Those packages are developed by me so I can put some common attributes like same sharedUserId or package name prefix.

My receiver should be invoked only when those packages are installed.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the onReceive() use intent.getIntExtra(Intent.[EXTRA_UID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_UID)); to get the UID of the added package. You can then compare this to a list of your own packages using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875916/how-to-get-uid-value-of-an-android-application-from-a-list-displayed-in-a-spinne) as a starting point

Comment: yes, that can be done; but my receiver will be launched anyway. I do not want to invoke my receiver for other packages; this is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You cannot specify the package name in the `<intent-filter>`, so if you are interested in getting these broadcast `Intent`s, you will need to get them all and just ignore the ones you don't care about.