# How to get Data usage on android by both wifi and Mobile data?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-data-usage, mobile-data

I need to get a data usage on each application installed on a android mobile.

Ex: I installed YouTube application on my mobile i need to get data usage of YouTube app by wifi and mobile data.

Excepted result:

YouTube - Wifi - 500MB.

YouTube - Mobile Data - 100 KB

I try to use TrafficStats API

```
int mobileTx = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
int mobileRx = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
int wifiTx = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mobileTx;
int wifiRx = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mobileRx;
```

the above give me the mobile entire data usage but i need to get per each application.

Answer (score 1):

`TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(int uid)` and `TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(int uid)` can help you out in this situation as these static methods provides info about bytes received and transmitted since last boot by some UID. for this you need to find UID of application for which you need detail. To find UID of application you can look into this thread - [How to get uid value of an android application from a list displayed in a spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875916/how-to-get-uid-value-of-an-android-application-from-a-list-displayed-in-a-spinne)

Comment: How to display the data usage like day,week and monthly wise?

Comment: System does not keep track of it by month, week or day. If you want functionality like this may be you track data used after installation of app and calculate periodically.

Comment: Thanks @deepak . I got data usage on each application. how to split mobile  and wifi data usage alone(per application).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [getUidTxBytes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidTxBytes(int)) API from TrafficStats class

```
long getUidTxBytes (int uid)
added in API level 8
Return number of bytes transmitted by the given UID since device boot. Counts packets across all network interfaces, and always increases monotonically since device boot. Statistics are measured at the network layer, so they include both TCP and UDP usage.
Before JELLY_BEAN_MR2, this may return UNSUPPORTED on devices where statistics aren't available.
Starting in N this will only report traffic statistics for the calling UID. It will return UNSUPPORTED for all other UIDs for privacy reasons. To access historical network statistics belonging to other UIDs, use NetworkStatsManager.
```

Although this also tells that you will have to make use of [NetworkStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html) to get network stats history of other than the calling apps.

Here uid is identifier of this process's uid

Comment: Hi I need to check these things (each application's data usage in specific time period/specific days) from my application.